# How to overcome Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly with C# extension

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I run into the problem where VSCode prompts

> Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly

For a C# project created using console template; when I debug it by pressing "F5" key.

I do not have any problems in compiling the project.

I have performed `dotnet run` on the project folder. I see the "Hello World" printed on the command prompt without any problem.

My version strings

```
VSCode    : 1.14.2
dotnet    : 2.0.0-preview2-25407-01
C# extn   : 1.11.0
OS        : Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 (Windows 7 - 64 bit)
```

I do not have any info in event log.

<s>How do I tackle this error?</s>

**[Update]**

**OmniSharp debug server is exiting/closing when they are launched suspiciously!
 Where do I collect the log for the OmniSharp debug server?**

*I do not have anything printed on my Output window in VS Code. I do not even see OmniSharp log source in the Output filter dropdown.*

**[Additional information]**

*Noted same error when I run the application in non-debug mode as well using "Ctrl+F5" key.*

*Browsed VS Code's source code in [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/fbece01268f4e5d290a470b328eea6312069eda0/src/vs/workbench/parts/debug/electron-browser/rawDebugSession.ts); the error message appears when debug server is not in disconnected state while exiting the server. Pursuing further on building a call graph, onServerExit are called*

*1. close event of the socket create in [connectServer] (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/fbece01268f4e5d290a470b328eea6312069eda0/src/vs/workbench/parts/debug/electron-browser/rawDebugSession.ts#L433)*

*2. exit event of the debug server process launched in [startServer] (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/fbece01268f4e5d290a470b328eea6312069eda0/src/vs/workbench/parts/debug/electron-browser/rawDebugSession.ts#L437)*

*Now my question gets refined to why is the debug server exiting / closing when they get created?*

*Could this be due to permissions or port numbers or something else? Where should I look for such problems in my machine?*

Comment: Please someone suggest something; or even better if more information is required pls ask!

Comment: With refined insight, I have narrowed the problem to be related to OmniSharp extension. It seems, the installation is not perfect! From https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/369 there should be a folder inside the extensions installation folder called "coreclr-debug". This is not there and neither the command 'csharp.downloadDebugger' worked. It throwed an error "not found".